# get lat lng from planet_osm_polygon.way in postgresql osm db

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I've downloaded some osm data into a postgresql db.  I'm trying to get lat lng coords from the 'planet_osm_polygon' table... field name 'way'.

I got pretty close with:

```
select ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(st_centroid(planet_osm_polygon.way),4626))
```

But it's not quite right, it gives me a result that's about 10 blocks off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG:4626 is local geodetic CRS for Madagaskar... I think you ment 4326...

```
select ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(st_centroid(way),4326))
from planet_osm_polygon
```

Comment: I do NOT know how you found that, but thanks!!! (I've been looking on http://www.spatialreference.org/ but can't figure it out)